# AngularJS, Unit testing a directive that uses a service that depends on some resources

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a directive that is using a service that uses some resources.  The issue that I have is when I mock the `get` method of my resource it will be mocked but the callback function will not be called. Therefore, the result won't be what is expected.

I tried to mock the resources by using `spyOn` as suggested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robinroestenburg/aDwva/), and also `$httpBackend.when`, but neither worked.  When I debug the code it will get to the get method but the get callback function never gets called and therefore, the inner callback `myCallback` that sets my value never gets called. 
I am not sure if my approach is even correct, I appreciate your suggestions.

/ Resource

```
.factory ('AirportTimeZone', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/airport/:airportId/timezone',{airportId: '@airportId'});
})
```

/ Service that is using my resources:

```
angular.module('localizationService', [])
.factory('LocalizationService', ['AirportTimeZone','CurrentLocalization',
     function (AirportTimeZone,CurrentLocalization) {

    function getAirportTimeZone(airport,myCallback){
      var options = {}
      var localOptions = AirportTimeZone.get({airportId:airport}, function(data){
          options.timeZone = data.timeZoneCode
          myCallback(options)
      });
    }
})
```

/ Directive

```
.directive('date',function (LocalizationService) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var airTimeZone
         function updateAirportTimeZone(_airportTimeZone){
            airTimeZone = _airportTimeZone.timeZone
            // call other stuff to do here
        }
        ....
        LocalizationService.getAirportTimeZone(airport,updateAirportTimeZone)
        ....
        element.text("something");
    }
});
```

/ Test

```
describe('Testing date directive', function() {
    var $scope, $compile;
    var $httpBackend,airportTimeZone,currentLocalization

    beforeEach(function (){
        module('directives');
        module('localizationService');
        module('resourcesService');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_,AirportTimeZone,CurrentLocalization) {
        $scope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        airportTimeZone=AirportTimeZone;
        currentLocalization = CurrentLocalization;

 //        spyOn(airportTimeZone, 'get').andCallThrough();
 //        spyOn(currentLocalization, 'get').andCallThrough();

    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
//        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/timezone').respond({timeZone:'America/New_York',locale:'us-en'});
//        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/airport/CMH/timezone').respond({timeZone:'America/New_York'});
    }))

    describe('Date directive', function () {
        var compileButton = function (markup, scope) {
            var el = $compile(markup)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            return el;
        };

        it('should',function() {
            var html = "<span date tz='airport' format='short' airport='CMH' >'2013-09-29T10:40Z'</span>"
            var element = compileButton(html,$scope)
            $scope.$digest();

            expected = "...."
            expect(element.html()).toBe(expected);


        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Might just be typos, but your LocalizationService doesn't look like valid JS (mismatched []), and you aren't returning anything from the factory, meaning the service would come out as undefined.
Also are you remembering to call `$httpBackend.flush()` after your compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented above:

After setting up responses with `$httpBackend.when`, you will still need to call `$httpBackend.flush()` to flush out the mocked response.

References: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend - *flushing http requests* section